# Wordpress menu of categories

Tags: wordpress, menu, categories

I have a horizontal menu for wordpress site and the menu items are categories. On clicking each menu item , I should show latest post for respective category.

e.g.

Item_1  Item_2  Item_3  Item_4 are my menu items. So on clicking Item_2, I should show latest post for that category of Item_2. Is this possible in Wordpress? I am just a newbie to wordpress, will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's how wordpress works.
Except, you have to create the categories in your admin dashboard and specify the cat you want when you are writing your post.

If you need info on how to build a template file, you should read http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

which explain how to write wordpress query.